# TestMethod For Checking If object is added successfully into table

Tags: .net, sql-server, unit-testing, async-await

So far I have this :

```
 using (var actContext = new ItsAllAboutTheGameDbContext(contextOptions))
        {
            var cardService = new CardService(actContext);
            creditCardResult = await cardService.AddCard("3242423532532434", "332", DateTime.Parse("02.03.2020"), user);
            actContext.CreditCards.Add(creditCardResult);
            await actContext.SaveChangesAsync();


        }

        //Assert
```

After I have added the card to CreditCards table in the context, how can I Assert if it was added successfully? And I need to check if it is added into the inmemorydatabase (actContext)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to assert that the data was inserted in the table?

You should inject a `DBContext` factory into your controller and use a fake one on your unit tests.

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(Func dbContextFactory) ...

...

```
    using (var actContext = dbContextFactory())
```

}

Then, in your test, you just inject a factory to mock context.

Better yet, inject a component in your controller.

Otherwise, you're left with querying the database to se if the data is there.

Comment: I have heard that it is somewhat in many cases useless to test the DBContext, because it is equal to testing if C# compiler works correctly.